# SecurityException: caller uid XXXX is different than the authenticator's uid

Tags: android

I received the above exception when trying to implement Sample Sync Adapter application. I have seen numerous posts related to this issue but no satisfactory response.

So I will jot down [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774282/securityexception-caller-uid-xxxx-is-different-than-the-authenticators-uid/5329490#5329490) here in case anyone else gets into the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. I ran into this problem and was able to find the solution more quickly thanks to your post.

Comment: Unfortunately, the posted link got broken in the meantime.  Does somebody have an alternative?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First, check the condition explained on [this post](http://loganandandy.tumblr.com/post/613041897/caller-uid-is-different):

[...] If you see an error from the `AccountManagerService` of the form `caller uid XXXX is different than the authenticator's uid`, it might be a bit misleading. The ‘authenticator’ in that message is not your authenticator class, it’s what Android understands to be the registered authenticator for the account’s type. The check that happens within the `AccountManagerService` looks like this:

```
 private void checkCallingUidAgainstAuthenticator(Account account) {
     final int uid = Binder.getCallingUid();
     if (account == null || !hasAuthenticatorUid(account.type, uid)) {
         String msg = "caller uid " + uid + " is different than the authenticator's uid";
         Log.w(TAG, msg);
         throw new SecurityException(msg);
     }
     if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
         Log.v(TAG, "caller uid " + uid + " is the same as the authenticator's uid");
     }
 }
```

Note that `hasAuthenticatorUid()` takes the `account.type`. This is where I’d screwed up. I was creating my `Account` with a type specified by a constant:

```
 class LoginTask {
     Account account = new Account(userId, AuthenticatorService.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
     ...
 }

 class AuthenticatorService extends Service {
     public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.joelapenna.foursquared";
     ...
 }
```

but this constant did not match the XML definition for my authenticator:

```
 <account-authenticator xmlns:android="/web/20150729061818/http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:accountType="com.joelapenna.foursquared.account" ... />
```

Second, if you are like me and want to embed the sample into your existing app for testing then, make sure you use `Constants` class that is part of this example and not under `android.provider.SyncStateContract` package. Because both classes use the same attribute name `ACCOUNT_TYPE` that is used when creating `Account` object.

Comment: Thanks! your first check solved the issue. And guess what, in a new project I had forgotten all about the authenticator xml file.!

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue, but only for some of my users.  I've double checked that the android:accountType in the authenticator.xml file matches the constant in my GenericAccountsService.  I also know that this exception doesn't occur for the vast majority of my apps users, but in my crash logs every now and then I see the crash for a handful of users. Any idea? Can the authenticator.xml file be modified somehow to cause this?

Comment: @clu Were you ever able to resolve your issue? I'm facing an identical scenario. This error only crops up for a small minority of my users: mostly on HTC One X, HTC One SV and HTC Desire 500's, as well as a smattering of many other devices as well.

Comment: @chandsie Same here. Only HTC devices seem to have this issue. It works fine for every other device.

Comment: @clu I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to solve this or find its root cause?

Comment: Thanks for the post, that was exactly my problem and I adhere "Incidentally, this is in a nutshell why I really dislike programming in XML."

Comment: I am having this problem. @clu were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 54):

Some other useful tips to debug problems like this.

First enable verbose logging for some tags:

```
$ adb shell setprop log.tag.AccountManagerService VERBOSE
$ adb shell setprop log.tag.Accounts VERBOSE
$ adb shell setprop log.tag.Account VERBOSE
$ adb shell setprop log.tag.PackageManager VERBOSE
```

You'll see logging like this:

```
V/AccountManagerService: initiating bind to authenticator type com.example.account
V/Accounts: there is no service connection for com.example.account
V/Accounts: there is no authenticator for com.example.account, bailing out
D/AccountManagerService: bind attempt failed for Session: expectLaunch true, connected false, stats (0/0/0), lifetime 0.002, addAccount, accountType com.example.account, requiredFeatures null
```

Which means that there is no authenticator registered for this account type. To see which authenticators are registered watch the log when installing the package:

```
D/PackageManager: encountered new type: ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.example.account}, ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.android.AuthenticatorService}, uid 10028
D/PackageManager: notifyListener: AuthenticatorDescription {type=com.example.account} is added
```

I had the problem that the authenticator xml descriptor referred to a string resource which didn't get resolved properly during the installation:

```
android:accountType="@string/account_type"
```

The logs showed

```
encountered new type: ServiceInfo: AuthenticatorDescription {type=@2131231194}, ...
```

Replacing it with a normal string (not resource) solved the problem. This seems to be Android 2.1 specific.

```
android:accountType="com.example.account"
```

Comment: This helped me torn down the issue.

Answer (score 25):

In my case the problem was very simply a mismatch in accountType declared in `res/xml/authenticator.xml` as `android:accountType="com.foo"` but referenced incorrectly as `"foo.com"` in creating the Account:

```
Account newAccount = new Account("dummyaccount", "foo.com");
```

Doh!

Comment: Hi, In my case accountType in xml and in newAccount object both are same. Still it's showing caller uid XXXX is different than the authenticator's uid error. why?

Answer (score 10):

There are few parts to implement custom account...

To invoke AccountManager in your Activity, something like that you already implemented...

```
Account account = new Account(username, ACCESS_TYPE);
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Bundle userdata = new Bundle();
userdata.putString("SERVER", "extra");

if (am.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, userdata)) {
    Bundle result = new Bundle();
    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, username);
    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, ACCESS_TYPE);
    setAccountAuthenticatorResult(result);
}
```

In res/xml/authenticator.xml you have to define your AccountAuthenticator data (responsible for your Authenticator UID). ACCESS_TYPE have to be the same string as your defined accountType in this xml!

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="de.buecherkiste"
    android:icon="@drawable/buecher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/buecher" >
</account-authenticator>
```

Finally you have to define your service your Manifest. Please do not forget the relevant permissions for manage your accounts (AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS / USE_CREDENTIALS / GET_ACCOUNTS / MANAGE_ACCOUNTS)

```
<service android:name=".AuthenticationService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
        android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
</service>
```

Answer (score 5):

My error was assuming the AccountManager getAccounts() method returned accounts only associated with my application context. I changed from

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
```

to

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
```

Answer (score 4):

The same error will appear if you put incorrect values in your intent-filters in your manifest.
I went through the android-dev tutorial on sync-adapters and ended up setting a bogus value for the "intent-filter/action android:name" as well as "meta-data/android:name" for syncadapter/accountauthenticator. This mistake caused the same errors to appear in the logs.

For the record, the correct values are: {android.content.SyncAdapter, android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator}

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your service XML is pointing to the correct location.

For instance if you're module name is

> com.example.module.auth

you're service android:name should be

```
<service android:name=".module.auth.name-of-authenticator-service-class"...
```

in AndriodManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a very silly mistake and was very hard to find.

In authenticator.xml I wrote

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="com.myapp"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
/>
```

instead of

```
<account-authenticator
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="com.myapp"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
/>
```

which was causing this error. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was permissions in manifest file
i had

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

it was all caps, when i changed it to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

problem was gone

Answer (score 1):

Also,

Check to see if you are treating the AccountType too much like a plain-old-String.

I have most of my code packaged under **com.mycompany.android**

I have been using the following AccountType with success: **com.mycompany.android.ACCOUNT**.

Now I have a desire to use multiple accounts, and when I try the approach of appending ".subType" on the end of my account, it fails with the

> caller uid xxxxx is different than the authenticator's uid

However, if I use "_subType" ( underscore instead of dot ), it works fine.

My guess is that somewhere under the hood Android is trying to treat com.mycompany.android.ACCOUNT as a legal package name, which it most certainly is not.

So, again:

**BAD** com.mycompany.android.ACCOUNT.subType

**GOOD** com.mycompany.android.ACCOUNT_subType

Answer (score 1):

First off, take another look at Jan Berkel's excellent debugging advice.

Finally, another thing to check is that your content provider and the authentication, and sync services are declared as children of the `application` tag.

```
    <application
        ...>
        <activity
            ...(Activity)...
        </activity>
        <provider
            ...(CP service declaration)/>

        <service
            ...(Authentication service declaration)...
        </service>

        <service
            ...(Sync service declaration)... 
        </service>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error, and all the above solutions are not working for you. Also, you assume that you have followed all the procedure. There may be a chance that the Authentication Service is developed by some other developer, which you want to make use of to Add Accounts.

What you can try is try signing your application with a release keystore. Now you run the application. I suppose this should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one possible solution.

I had this error when my user was registered in my app with the same e-mail as his android google account.

So, when I tried to `accountManager.getAccounts()` and search for this e-mail I found an account with the same e-mail BUT with another account type. So, when trying to use this (google.com) account I get this error.

So, the right way to find an account is:

```
public Account findAccount(String accountName) {
    for (Account account : accountManager.getAccounts())
        if (TextUtils.equals(account.name, accountName) && TextUtils.equals(account.type, "myservice.com"))
            return account;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You could call `accountManager.getAccountsByType("myservice.com")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your AccountAuthenticatorService has the prover intent filters ;

ie.

```
<service android:name=".service.AccountAuthenticatorService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                    android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
 </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this exception at Samsung devices be sure that you are not using [safe mode](http://www.androidcentral.com/galaxy-note-4-safe-mode).

Answer (score 0):

If same apps are from different store ,for example amazon app store and google play store , eventually security exception gonna be thrown as the signature of the apps would be different in this case .If u had planned to  use same authenticator for the purpose of single sign in , either of the app would crash. i had encountered this trouble once. Especially amazon app store would sign its apps with its own signature for the purpose of security.

Note: If there is no typo error or other answers mentioned here , please check for the signature of the apps in case of single sign in.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still expierienced issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37102317/4171098

> In my case I accidently defined AuthenticatorService in the Manifest
>   outside the `<application>` tags. Moving the declaration inside
>   `<application>` fixed the issue. Hope will help someone.