# getting caller uid 10066 is different than the authenticator's uid

Tags: android, accountmanager

I am using following code  to add account into Account list

```
final AccountManager accountMgr = AccountManager.get(this.getApplicationContext());
 Account ac = new Account("my.id","com.google");
try{
      accountMgr.addAccountExplicitly(ac, "password", null);}
catch(Exception e){
 String str = e.getLocalizedMessage();
 Log.e("err",str);
}
```

but getting following error everytime:
'caller uid 10066 is different than the authenticator's uid'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following stackoverflow question seems to deal with the issue:

[SecurityException: caller uid XXXX is different than the authenticator's uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774282/securityexception-caller-uid-xxxx-is-different-than-the-authenticators-uid)

The article it links to ( http://loganandandy.tumblr.com/post/613041897/caller-uid-is-different ) explains the whole thing, though it took me a minute to realise what part of my code the last xml snippet was referring to.

I ended up storing my account type and auth token type in my strings.xml and referencing them  in the authenticator.xml and code as needed.

Comment: Good idea to store it just once and reference it from both places.

Comment: @Tzrlk can you please show some code on what you did? Thanks!

Comment: So I'm still getting this crash even though I don't have the mismatch in my XML file.  In fact, the crash occurs randomly on very few people's devices.  Is this happening consistently for all of you?