# How to solve "caller uid XXXX is different than the authenticator's uid" issue?

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager

I am getting this error at `AccountManager.get(this).getPassword(account)`

How to solve this.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774282/securityexception-caller-uid-xxxx-is-different-than-the-authenticators-uid

Hope this helps...

Comment: i have seen this before but its not giving any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this on accounts whose authenticator was signed with the same key as your app (i.e. you are the provider of the authenticator). If you are not, you cannot directly read the password for security reasons. But any good authenticator does not store the password anyway, but a token instead. If you need to access an existing account that's provided by a different app, using OAuth as outlined in the [Account Manager: Using other accounts](http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-using-other-accounts) article should work for you.