# SecurityException when trying to add an account

Tags: android, accountmanager

I'm experimenting with Android `AccountManager`.

I have an Account authentication service that shows UI to enter username/password.

I go to Settings/Accounts/Add Account, choose my new account type and I'm presented with the UI.

When I click OK I get the following error

```
04-24 14:48:29.334: E/AndroidRuntime(386): java.lang.SecurityException: 
    caller uid 10035 is different than the authenticator's uid
```

The only method of MyAccountAuthenticationService:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new MyAccountAuthenticator(this).getIBinder();
}
```

MyAccountAuthenticator:

```
@Override
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, 
    String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, 
    Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {

    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAccountCreatorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
}
```

Fragment of `MyAccountCreatorActivity`'s `onClick`

```
AccountManager accManager = AccountManager.get(this);
Account newAccount = new Account(email, MyAccountAuthenticator.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
accManager.setPassword(newAccount, password);
```

Exception is thrown on `setPassword`. I already required all the accounting permissions. I'm not sure about what could be causing this. If you need more code/information please ask.

Thank you.

Comment: see this http://loganandandy.tumblr.com/post/613041897/caller-uid-is-different maybe helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityException: caller uid XXXX is different than the authenticator's uid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774282/securityexception-caller-uid-xxxx-is-different-than-the-authenticators-uid)

Comment: @rds sorry it's not a dupe. The original XML had a typo, however Android will not explain you exactly the real nature of the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @imran khan, I discovered that my constant value didn't match "exactly" what was in the authenticator XML definition

Comment: I don't understand how your "authenticator XML definition" is different from the answer about the AndroidManifest.  Did you have to match your AndroidManifest or was the answer elsewhere?

Comment: if I mistype org.zighinetto.myapp.account as org.zighinetto.myap.account it won't work. It was simply defined one way in the XML and another way in the code (public static final String... you know...)

Answer (score 17):

Seems obvious, but you will also see this error if your authenticator service has not been defined in AndroidManifest.xml. For example:

```
<service android:name="your.AuthService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
         android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question didn't state that I already wrote the XML, in that case with a syntax glitch

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I got this error when I ran two different flavors on the same device. The second one was trying to access the same account as the first, which caused the error.

Comment: I had the same problem on an Android 5 phone, which I fixed by changing the flavor dimension name, thanks to your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I accidently defined AuthenticatorService in the Manifest outside the `<application>` tags. Moving the declaration inside `<application>` fixed the issue. Hope will help someone.