# Setting up Google phone Account programmatically

Tags: android, accountmanager, google-account

I am interested in adding and setting up a hard-coded Google Account with a given username and password programmatically on the phone without any user intervention.

I have tried using

```
AccountsManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount("xxxxxx@gmail.com","com.google",password,null)
```

It works perfectly for all the `accountsType` except for the **com.google** `accountsType` throwing the "uid not matching authenticator
id" exception.

I have already followed all the suggestions given in this particular thread for fixing the error but of no use, the error persists for **com.google** accounts type

[SecurityException: caller uid XXXX is different than the authenticator's uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774282/securityexception-caller-uid-xxxx-is-different-than-the-authenticators-uid)

The other alternative approach I tried was using the `samplesyncadapter` code, it works perfectly fine, the authentication part is done in `NetworkUtilities` file which I believe need to be changed to Google accounts `clientlogin`

Is there anyway this can be performed directly without user intervention for captcha??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after few months, I managed to solve this issue. Might be helpful to someone.

The solution is not generic but quite specific to emulator/device LCD characteristic and ugly.

I used MonkeyRunner to issue touch, press and key events at specified screen coordinates to reach Home->Apps->Settings->Accounts and Sync->Add Account->Google->Next->Sign In and so on

More details about MonkeyRunner can be found here

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html