# AccountManager doesn't allow adding a new account in application (caller uid is different than the authenticator's uid)

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager

before I start, I want to emphasize that I read some answers and they don't help me. Like:

[Duplicate problem ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139736/android-accountmanager-addaccountexplicitly-is-stopping-my-app)

[addAccountExplicitly throws IllegalStateException caused by Securityexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178022/addaccountexplicitly-throws-illegalstateexception-caused-by-securityexception)

[SecurityException: caller uid XXXX is different than the authenticator's uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774282/securityexception-caller-uid-xxxx-is-different-than-the-authenticators-uid)
...

like the title suggestes, I am trying to use AccountManager in an Activty under Application (not Service), but without sucess. I use an 4.3 emulator (Intel image). I can easly liist all accounts on the emulator (added via android interface) but when I want to create one an Error comes in:

```
09-14 13:21:21.863: E/AndroidRuntime(3291): java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10046 is different than the authenticator's uid
09-14 13:21:21.863: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
09-14 13:21:21.863: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
09-14 13:21:21.863: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.addAccountExplicitly(IAccountManager.java:719)
09-14 13:21:21.863: E/AndroidRuntime(3291):     at android.accounts.AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(AccountManager.java:612)
```

Here are my quick code snippets:

Login.java ->

```
public class Login extends AccountAuthenticatorActivity {
...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    ...
        AccountManager accountmanager = AccountManager.get(this);

        Account userAccount = new Account(“Test”, “test.activities”);

        if (accountmanager.addAccountExplicitly(userAccount, “pass”, null))
        System.out.println(“Added success”);
        else System.out.println(“Added failed”);

    }
...
}
```

res/xml/authenticator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="test.activities"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"                 
/>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name="Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/cg_icon_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
      >       

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                 android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Tried it on 2.2 Android phone and the error is the same. I can succesfully list all the Accounts although (with *Account[] accounts =  accountmanager.getAccounts();*).
I also tried this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.udinic.accounts_example and can add the account with it. But via my application, no success.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue? Would be useful for others stuck in the same issue..