# caller uid yyyy is different than authenticator's uid

Tags: accountmanager

I am trying to use addAccountExplicitly() I am getting the error caller uid yyyy is different than authenticator's uid. I have included all the necessary permissions in androidmanifest.xml. Do I need to do anything more for this thing to work? Please help me. I am using Android Studio as development environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityException: caller uid XXXX is different than the authenticator's uid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774282/securityexception-caller-uid-xxxx-is-different-than-the-authenticators-uid)

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered by Geoff in 
[SecurityException: caller uid XXXX is different than the authenticator's uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774282/securityexception-caller-uid-xxxx-is-different-than-the-authenticators-uid)

Geoff's reply for that question:
Finally, another thing to check is that your content provider and the authentication, and sync services are declared as children of the application tag.

service tag was placed outside  tag in my AndroidManifest.xml. Once, I made service tag child of , things started working.