# SecurityException on AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly() for shared android module

Tags: android, android-authenticator, android-securityexception

I've been following Android's [Creating a Sync Adapter (BasicSyncAdapter)](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) to start out my own sync service logic.

**The problem**: Upon invoking `AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly()`, a `SecurityException` is raised, claiming a mismatch between caller and authenticator UID's:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10048 is different than the authenticator's uid
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
        at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.addAccount(IAccountManager.java:580)
        at android.accounts.AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(AccountManager.java:565)
```

**App / Library Structure**: My app is divided into two modules (gradle / android studio projects):

- Android Library (`com.example.mylib`), which contains the sources and xml's necessary for defining a sync service, adapter, authenticator, etc.
- Android Application: to test/demo the library functionality (`com.example.mylib.app`).

This seems relevant, since the two apps are of different packages. For this reason **I've set up the `sharedUserId` property in the two project manifests** (and according to the `packages.xml` snippets below, it seems to be set up correctly).

**All required permissions seem to be set up correctly** (namely: `READ_SYNC_SETTINGS`, `WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS`, `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS`, `USE_CREDENTIALS`, `GET_ACCOUNTS` and `MANAGE_ACCOUNTS`).

I've also set **explicit values for manifest properties** (and not going through `@string/...` expansions) - see below.

Also tried clean builds, clean installs, restarts, etc.

Tech details / dumps follow.

---

### Environment / Setup

- Using Android Studio (version 1.3)
- `targetSdkVersion` is 22 (for both projects)
- Running on an emulator (genymotion)

### System logcat dumps

Following the advice mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774282/securityexception-caller-uid-xxxx-is-different-than-the-authenticators-uid), I've checked **Android System Logcat's** seem to be alright as well (until the exception is encountered):

Before (clean installation):

```
08-10 10:43:39.375    9015-9031/system_process D/PackageManager﹕ New package installed in /data/app/example.mylib.app-1.apk
08-10 10:43:39.387    9015-9027/system_process D/PackageManager﹕ generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 3 services unchanged
08-10 10:43:39.387    9015-9027/system_process D/PackageManager﹕ generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 6 services:
    New service added: ServiceInfo: SyncAdapterType {name=com.example.mylib.provider, type=com.example.mylib.provider.ACCOUNT, userVisible=false, supportsUploading=false, isAlwaysSyncable=true, allowParallelSyncs=false, settingsActivity=null}, ComponentInfo{com.example.mylib.app/com.example.mylib.service.SyncService}, uid 10048
08-10 10:43:39.739    9015-9015/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.mylib.app/.MyActivity u=0} from pid 19237
08-10 10:43:39.791    9015-9025/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.example.mylib.app for activity com.example.mylib.app/.MyActivity: pid=19247 uid=10048 gids={3003, 1028}
```

After stepping through `addAccountExplicitly()`:

```
08-10 10:45:56.479    9015-9270/system_process V/AccountManagerService﹕ addAccount: Account {name=100, type=com.example.mylib.provider.ACCOUNT}, caller's uid 10048, pid 19247
08-10 10:45:56.479    9015-9270/system_process V/AccountManagerService﹕ caller uid 10048 has android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS
08-10 10:45:56.479    9015-9270/system_process W/AccountManagerService﹕ caller uid 10048 is different than the authenticator's uid
```

### Packages Dump

The interesting snippets from `/data/system/packages.xml` seem to be alright:

```
...
<package name="com.example.mylib.app"
    codePath="/data/app/com.example.mylib.app-1.apk" 
    nativeLibraryPath="/data/data/com.example.mylib.app/lib" 
    flags="0" ft="14f170308d8" it="14f16d8b51b" ut="14f17030a42" version="1"
    sharedUserId="10048">
    <sigs count="1">
        <cert index="4" />
    </sigs>
    <perms />
</package>

...
<shared-user name="com.example.mylib" userId="10048">
<sigs count="1">
    <cert index="4" />
</sigs>
    <perms>
        <item name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
        <item name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
        <item name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
        <item name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
        <item name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <item name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <item name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    </perms>
</shared-user>
```

### Project Manifests

Library project's `mylib_authenticator.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:sharedUserId="com.example.mylib"
    android:accountType="com.example.mylib.provider.ACCOUNT"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/service_name"/>
```

Library project's `mylib_syncadapter.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:sharedUserId="com.example.mylib"
    android:contentAuthority="com.example.mylib.provider"
    android:accountType="com.example.mylib.provider.ACCOUNT"
    android:userVisible="false"
    android:exported="true"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
    />
```

Interesting bits from the library project's `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mylib"
android:sharedUserId="com.example.mylib">

<application>

    <provider
        android:name="com.example.mylib.provider.MyContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.mylib.provider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:syncable="true"/>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.mylib.service.SyncService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/mylib_syncadapter" />
    </service>

    <service android:name="com.example.mylib.service.AccountService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.AccountAuthenticator"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/mylib_authenticator" />
    </service>

</application>
```

Interesting bits from app project's `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mylib.app"
    android:sharedUserId="com.example.mylib">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>

    <application ...>
        <activity ... />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You got the solution for this ??